# Use datePicker as a timer which sends local notifications

Tags: ios, timer, datepicker, uilocalnotification

I have a datePicker and I want to use it as a timer. The timer should send a notification when the time is over. But i don't know how to do this, because it only works when I use the picker as a "date collector".

```
NSDate *date = [self.datePicker date];
...

UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = date;
```

But how should i rewrite this for a datePicker with "Count Down Timer" mode?
Thanks for your response ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `countDownDuration` from the date picker and add it to the current date:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = self.datePicker.countDownDuration;
NSDate *fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:duration];
```

This assumes you are using a `UIDatePicker` in `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` mode.